# Loop through rows in an excel worksheet and copy a range if the cell isn't blank

Tags: vba, excel, while-loop

I have virtually no VBA experience except that, from what I have seen other spreadsheets do, I am convinced this must be possible. I have searched all over but cannot find any explanations to help or code I can just use. I hope someone can help.

I have a download from our website cart which does not format the data how it needs to be to then up-load into some new sales order/invoice generating software.

As an example here is a link to an image that shows how the data currently looks(the workbook is called 'Orders.csv' but I can convert to xlsx if needed):

http://web225.extendcp.co.uk/fiercepc.co.uk/img1.jpg

As you can see if the customer purchases more than one product (not qty of a product, a completely different product) it is listed across the row. The first product is starts at column H, the second from column O, the third from column V and so on.

I need the data to be displayed as follows:

http://web225.extendcp.co.uk/fiercepc.co.uk/img2.jpg

So each product is listed below each other and with the same customer details before it. This is so the invoicing software can check each order ID and create an invoice accordingly showing all the different products.

I have no idea how to go about this. I guess it needs to be a looping macro that checks if a row has data in a cell and then copies ranges accordingly. Also, the macro would need to be in a different workbook (maybe called macros) so it acts on this download as it will be a new workbook each time it is downloaded. I hope this makes sense.

I'm sure this will be very easy for somebody, just not me. Please help! Ideally I need the macro with explanations so I can manipulate the ranges etc as this is only an example spreadsheet, the actual sheet is much bigger and contains more data.

Comment: `I have virtually no VBA experience` Are you willing to learn VBA? What you want can be easily achieved by looping as you correctly mentioned

Comment: Yes definitely happy to learn VBA. I used to work as an Accountant and used spreadsheets all the time, so I am very good with formulas and I used to pull apart other peoples macros to suit my needs, but I just can't get my head around this problem. I started my own business a couple of years ago and as I haven't used Excel for such a long time I am very rusty with VBA. Where I used to work I had pulled together a spreadsheet that did a similar thing to what I need now, but I cannot find it. Any help/training you can provide would be very much appreciated. I have never posted on a forum before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get an answer to my own question from elsewere, but thought I'd share the answer with everyone who might be interested as the reply was spot on and indepth.

```
'****This macro is to use on sheets within the same workbook
'****If you want to transfer your data to another workbook you
'****will have to alter the code somewhat, but the idea is the same

Sub copydata()
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Ouput sheet") 'whatever you worksheet is
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Orders") 'or whatever your worksheet is called


'Item 1 - I'm calling the separate sections where each item ordered is in your worksheet Item 1, Item 2
'this encompasses columns H-N for item 1, etc, etc
r = 3 'this is the first row where your data will output
x = 3 'this is the first row where you want to check for data
Do Until ws2.Range("A" & x) = "" 'This will loop until column A is empty, set the column to whatever you want
                            'but it cannot have blanks in it, or it will stop looping. Choose a column that is
                            'always going to have data in it.

If Not ws2.Range("H" & x).Value = "" Then 'This checks your column H to make sure it's not empty
                                            'If empty, it goes on to the next line, if not it copies the data.
                                            'This column should be something that will have something in it if
                                            'there is a product ordered for Item 1
                                            'i.e. don't choose column J if it will have blanks where there is
                                            'actually an item ordered

'this section copies the data, the worksheet left of the = sign is the one data will be written to
    ws1.Range("A" & r).Value = ws2.Range("A" & x).Value 'Order Date
    ws1.Range("B" & r).Value = ws2.Range("B" & x).Value 'Order ID
    ws1.Range("C" & r).Value = ws2.Range("C" & x).Value 'Customer
    ws1.Range("D" & r).Value = ws2.Range("D" & x).Value 'Billing Add
    ws1.Range("E" & r).Value = ws2.Range("E" & x).Value 'Subtotal
    ws1.Range("F" & r).Value = ws2.Range("F" & x).Value 'Tax Amount
    ws1.Range("G" & r).Value = ws2.Range("G" & x).Value 'Total Amount
    ws1.Range("H" & r).Value = ws2.Range("H" & x).Value 'Product ID
    ws1.Range("I" & r).Value = ws2.Range("I" & x).Value 'Column J - couldn't read your headings for a few of these
    ws1.Range("J" & r).Value = ws2.Range("J" & x).Value 'Column K
    ws1.Range("K" & r).Value = ws2.Range("K" & x).Value 'L
    ws1.Range("L" & r).Value = ws2.Range("L" & x).Value 'Price
    ws1.Range("M" & r).Value = ws2.Range("M" & x).Value 'Attributes

    r = r + 1 'Advances r and x when there is a matching case
    x = x + 1
Else
    x = x + 1 'Advances only x (to check the next line) when there is not a matching case,
                'i.e. your output line stays on the next line down from where it last wrote data
                'while x advances
End If
Loop 'End of Item 1


'Item 2

x = 3 'this time we only define x, we want r to stay where it's at so it can continue copying the data into one
    'seamless list
Do Until ws2.Range("A" & x) = "" 'still want this to stay the same

If Not ws2.Range("O" & x).Value = "" Then 'This one needs to change to match the column in your second Item

'the ranges on ws1 will stay the same, ws2 ranges pertaining to customer data stay the same, ws2 ranges pertaining
'to specific Item 2 info will change
    ws1.Range("A" & r).Value = ws2.Range("A" & x).Value 'Order Date       *SAME
    ws1.Range("B" & r).Value = ws2.Range("B" & x).Value 'Order ID       *SAME
    ws1.Range("C" & r).Value = ws2.Range("C" & x).Value 'Customer       *SAME
    ws1.Range("D" & r).Value = ws2.Range("D" & x).Value 'Billing Add       *SAME
    ws1.Range("E" & r).Value = ws2.Range("E" & x).Value 'Subtotal       *SAME
    ws1.Range("F" & r).Value = ws2.Range("F" & x).Value 'Tax Amount       *SAME
    ws1.Range("G" & r).Value = ws2.Range("G" & x).Value 'Total Amount       *SAME
    ws1.Range("H" & r).Value = ws2.Range("O" & x).Value 'Product ID       *CHANGED!!!!
    ws1.Range("I" & r).Value = ws2.Range("P" & x).Value 'Column J       *CHANGED!!!!
    ws1.Range("J" & r).Value = ws2.Range("Q" & x).Value 'Column K       *CHANGED!!!!
    ws1.Range("K" & r).Value = ws2.Range("R" & x).Value 'L       *CHANGED!!!!
    ws1.Range("L" & r).Value = ws2.Range("S" & x).Value 'Price       *CHANGED!!!!
    ws1.Range("M" & r).Value = ws2.Range("T" & x).Value 'Attributes       *CHANGED!!!!

    r = r + 1 'Advances r and x when there is a matching case
    x = x + 1
Else
    x = x + 1 'Advances only x (to check the next line) when there is not a matching case,
                'i.e. your output line stays on the next line down from where it last wrote data
                'while x advances
End If
Loop 'End of Item 2
'simply copy Item 2 code and change the appropriate values to match Items 3,4,5,6, etc, etc


'You will get a list of all the info for Item 1, follow by all info for Item 2, etc, etc
'i.e. if Paul orders 2 items, they won't end up right below each other, but his second
'item will end up farther down, but will still be on the list
'If this is not what you want you could sort afterwards or alter the code, but it is a significant alteration

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be:

1. Loop through rows
2. For each rows, get number of occupied columns.
3. Find number of orders in row by simple math(assuming each product order occupies same number of columns)
4. Loop over the orders - Copy the product data in new sheet
5. For each of these copy operations, copy customer data from the row under process in outermost loop.
6. As for the last requirement. Open the workbook orders.csv(assuming the filename and location remain the same) in you macro and do all the operations mentioned above onto it.

I can write it for you. But, it would be a good learning experience for you if you write it on your own. You will able find answers to most of your queries(like how to get number of occupied columns in a row etc.) here on stackoverflow.

Also, go through this page to get started on Excel VBA:
http://www.functionx.com/vbaexcel/

Comment: Thanks for spending the time to reply. As much as I would love to, I just don't have the time to learn the code from scratch (the stresses of owning your own small business). It is not something I will be using in my everyday life. I will try to follow the instructions you have left, but was hoping for some basic code with instructions so I could pull it apart and use it as needed.

Comment: i'll try to put together something for you..

and i would recommend you to learn VBA in your free time..
excel is a very powerful tool when wielded by correct hands and you can leverage its power to benefit your business in many way...

Comment: Of course, that's superb. I am also trying to get my head around 'Access' which I have never used, so you're help on this is very much appreciated.

Comment: I still really need this macro if someone can help.