# Copy range of values

Tags: excel, vba, copy, range

Hi I need to copy a particular range of cells and iterate through rows and continue the copying process until a null value is encountered . Hard to get the code 
please help

Comment: At least build a part of the code yourself. Parts can be found with google easily.

Comment: Use `Do While` to loop, `If` to check if the cell is `null`, and `Exit Do` to exit the loop. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933425/loop-through-rows-in-an-excel-worksheet-and-copy-a-range-if-the-cell-isnt-blank?rq=1) which is similar.

Comment: I did build the code, but not able to iterate through rows.

Comment: a) no sample data b) no sample code c) no expected results d) no show of an original effort (see a, b and c). Definitely a minus 1 from me. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sry for that ! ws.Range("B11", "G11").Copy I just want to know how to increment the cell to (B12,G12) and so on

Comment: You can use all kind of loops for that (for, while, ...). There is plenty of subject like this on the forum and on internet. Just take a look around and you'll find your answer for sure because it is **such a classical question**. Easy way is to define a string variable to make "B11:G11" become "B12:G12" and so on.

Comment: Take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29208949/4628637

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:B4")
    ' loop trought each row in selected column Columns(1) = first column in range
    For Each onlyDefinedColumnRow In rng.Columns(1).Rows
        If IsEmpty(onlyDefinedColumnRow) Then Exit For
    i = i + 1
    Next onlyDefinedColumnRow
    ' or loop trought each cell in range
    'For Each cell In rng.Rows
    '    If IsEmpty(cell) Then Exit For
    'i = i + 1
    'Next cell

rng.Resize(i).Copy Destination:=Cells(i + 2, 1)
```